# How to dynamically generate key names in Cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to dynamically set the path of the sql file in the code below using parameters.

```
files: 
  /tmp/setup.mysql: 
    content: !Sub |
      CREATE DATABASE ${DBName};
      CREATE USER '${DBUsername}'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '${DBPassword}';
      GRANT ALL ON ${DBName}.* TO '${DBUsername}'@'localhost';
      FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    mode: "000644"
    owner: "root"
    group: "root"
```

I have tried simplistically adding a Reference to a custom Path parameters but, unfortunately, I am getting the following error from the Template Designer.

```
Template contains errors.: Template format error: [/Resources/MyLaunchConfig/Metadata/AWS::CloudFormation::Init/config/files] map keys must be strings; received a map instead
```

How can I move a path like this into the template parameters?

#### Edit:

The Note on the CloudFormation documentation on [Intrinsic functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) says the following:

> You can use intrinsic functions only in specific parts of a template.
> Currently, you can use intrinsic functions in resource properties,
> outputs, metadata attributes, and update policy attributes. You can
> also use intrinsic functions to conditionally create stack resources.

This seems to indicate that the functions should be available in resource properties and metadata attributes. It does not specifically restrict it to the values in these objects rather than the keys (although this could be assumed by the inherent nature of keys vs values).

Comment: Where do you set the path dynamically?

Comment: I would replace `/tmp/setup.mysql` with `!Ref sqlFilePath`, for example. I'd prefer to replace the `/tmp` part only but that gets into a more complicated use case. I just need to know if there is a way to use a parameter or function in a key name (as opposed to using it in a key value).

Comment: Sadly you can't do this. But you could if you used `UserData` to create the file instead of cfn init.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. I've been unsuccessful in making this work so it would appear that you are correct. Do you have a reference that documents this restriction?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. I think this comes from more general specification of how CFN syntax work. If you don't mind, I will provide an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments.

The issue is that according to the [CFN format specification](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-resource-specification-format.html), a `map` can only be string:

> A **map** is a collection of key-value pairs, where the **keys are always strings**.

Therefore, a proposed solution was to use `UserData` to define the dynamically generate file, instead of using CFN metadata.

Comment: Understood that keys are always strings. However, I'm not clear why this doesn't mean I can use a reference to a parameter of type string. The `Ref` function will return a string and therefore satisfy the requirement of the key being a string. I suppose one could argue that `Ref` provides variable types based on the specific parameter/reference but if this is the case we could switch the function to `Sub` which should always return a string.

Comment: @RichC I know what you mean, but this is how it works sadly. AWS made such a design decision when developing CloudFormation and I don't have an answer what were rationale for that.